# How to use # in href without terminating rest of the link in link tag

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

So! I wants to use **#** symbol in the middle of text as link of a tag. I have searched about this problem but unable to find solution

Basically I'm trying to download a string using javascript which is just a csv string. I wants to download that string as a csv file.
I'm using the code below to achieve that but symbole **"#"** is casing issue because it is terminating rest of the string because that is how href works

```
csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,sep=;\r\n a;b;c#;d;e;f "
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
window.location = encodedUri
```

In above code, **";d;e;f"** will be ignored and file will not be downloaded completely
Can anyone please help me to download string which includes # in it as text file?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it? i.e. `\#` like you did with the newline (`\n`)

Comment: Are you asking how you can escape the `#`? Usually its `%23` You should use `encodeURIComponent` not `encodeURI` and use that function each individual 'part' of the thing you are encoding, not the entire resulting string.

Comment: @AaronMeese Escaping is not working. It is returning # itself after escaping it

Comment: @Evert Thank!
I was able to download whole file but symbols like ;, space, comma  and hashes were replaced with "%(some digit)"
I was unable to download file with any symbol

Comment: sounds like you double-encoded the string.